# App keeps crashing at random moments Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Im making a space invaders game and it keeps crashing for the same reason.
the code that has a "bug" in it is:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & missileCategory) != 0 &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & alienCategory) != 0 {
            destroyAlien(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }
}
```

And the crash error is:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: So either `firstBody.node` is nil, or `secondBody.node` is nil, and your force-unwrapping them causing a crash.

Comment: When you use `!` and `as!` you get the potential for your app to crash if a value is _nil_. Try replacing all `!` with `?` and get your app to compile that way.

Comment: how do i not force unwrap them? @Michael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35876779/210171

Comment: You may need to change `destroyAlien` to take Optionals as parameters if it doesn't already. Then you can use `as?` instead of `as!`.

Comment: What should i change it to? @Michael

Comment: I will put it in an answer as it's a bit long...

Comment: Nvm i got it i change SKSpriteNode to SKSpriteNode? @Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're force-unwrapping `firstBody.node` and `secondBody.node` using `as!`. If either of them are nil, your app will crash. You should change `destroyAlien` to take parameters that are Optionals, and then use `as?`.

```
func destroyAlien(node1: SKSpriteNode?, alien node2: SKSpriteNode?) {
    if let node1 = node1 {
        // node1 not nil
    }
    if let node2 = node2 {
        // node2 not nil
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & missileCategory) != 0 &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & alienCategory) != 0 {
            destroyAlien(firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode)
    }
}
```

This assumes you want to allow one or both to be nil. If neither should ever be nil, you have a logic error earlier in your code.